# Get NOT_BUILT build result in Jenkins when building maven project with selective dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I have a multi-component maven project in Jenkins. This project has a `Send Files over FTP` Post-Build step. I have set my mvn goals to build just my desired component; not all of them:

```
clean install -pl component-x,component-y -P develop -X
```

All the dependencies in my project are built successfully;

```
[INFO] component-x ............................ SUCCESS [  5.026 s]
[INFO] component-y ............................ SUCCESS [ 16.912 s]
```

but the Jenkins says:

```
FTP: Current build result is [NOT_BUILT], not going to run.
```

**EDIT 1:**
Yes, I have read [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16240). People suggestions include:

1. Do it manually.
2. Use *Execute Shell* instead.

But there were no solution for *How to do it manually*.

BTW I have an FTP server which I want to put files on; it's not possible for me to use *Execute Shell*.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like because of this bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16240

Either you can set the status to success manually or use execute shell for ftp instead of the plugin.

You can run a post build groovy script `manager.buildSuccess()`
See [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin#GroovyPostbuildPlugin-Changelog)

Comment: Yes, I have read that issue (maybe it was better to put it in the main question). There were no solution for *How to do it manually*. BTW I have an FTP server which I want to put files on; it's not possible for me to use *Execute Shell*.

Comment: You can run a post build groovy script manager.buildSuccess() See [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin#GroovyPostbuildPlugin-Changelog)

Comment: @yausename, I'll try and let you know about the results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the Publish over FTP plugin checks if the build was successful. Unstable is accepted, too, but NOT_BUILT isn't. If the build is not considered successful, the plugin refuses to run.

It is arguable, if that is an expected behavior. The user might want to transfer files, even if the build was not successful. Besides, the NOT_BUILT obviously refers only to the last build step, not to the overall result which is still SUCCESS.

There is an issue filed under [JENKINS-55816](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55816).

I've created a patch that does not check for the build result which [can be downloaded from here](https://download.savignano.net/misc/publish-over-ftp-plugin/) (use at your own risk, with no warranty whatsoever).